# Cannot access virtual hosts directory after configure apache

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, forbidden

My virtual hosts have this configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin klebermo@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /home/kleber/www/kleber
        ServerName klebermota.eti.br
        ServerAlias www.klebermota.eti.br
</VirtualHost>
```

in my `apache2.conf` i have this configuration:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

when I try access the domain, I gor the error: `You don't have permission to access this resource.`  (for any directory from the virtual host)

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

```
pwd
/home/kleber
ls -la
total 287612
drwxr-xr-x 8 kleber kleber      4096 Mar 13 18:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root        4096 Mar 13 16:10 ..
-rw------- 1 kleber kleber       905 Mar 13 21:28 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 kleber kleber       220 Mar 13 16:10 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 kleber kleber      3771 Mar 13 16:10 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 kleber kleber      4096 Mar 13 16:13 .cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 kleber kleber         0 Mar 13 16:10 .cloud-locale-test.skip
drwx------ 3 kleber kleber      4096 Mar 13 16:13 .gnupg
drwxrwxr-x 3 kleber kleber      4096 Mar 13 16:58 .local
-rw-r--r-- 1 kleber kleber       807 Mar 13 16:10 .profile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kleber kleber 294462718 Mar 13 16:45 file.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x 2 kleber kleber      4096 Mar 13 16:35 sql
drwxrwxr-x 2 kleber kleber      4096 Mar 13 16:31 webapp
drwxrwxr-x 8 kleber kleber      4096 Mar 13 16:56 www
cd www
pwd
/home/kleber/www
ls -la
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 8 kleber kleber   4096 Mar 13 16:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 kleber kleber   4096 Mar 13 18:08 ..
drwxrwxr-x 5 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 13 17:25 ciencia
drwxrwxr-x 5 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 13 17:26 dailymaker
drwxrwxr-x 5 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 13 17:26 dailymaker_br
drwxrwxr-x 5 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 13 17:25 kleber
drwxrwxr-x 5 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 13 17:25 robotica
drwxrwxr-x 5 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 13 17:26 vidacrista
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
ps aux | grep apache
root     27348  0.0  0.9 193912 19408 ?        Ss   22:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27349  0.0  0.5 194440 11920 ?        S    22:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27350  0.0  0.5 194440 12128 ?        S    22:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27351  0.0  0.5 194440 11912 ?        S    22:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27352  0.0  0.5 194448 12084 ?        S    22:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27353  0.0  0.5 194440 12128 ?        S    22:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27354  0.0  0.5 194448 11820 ?        S    22:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27363  0.0  0.5 194440 11920 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27440  0.0  0.5 194440 11968 ?        S    23:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27441  0.0  0.5 194440 11924 ?        S    23:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
kleber   27442  0.0  0.5 194440 11924 ?        S    23:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     27542  0.0  0.0   8152   856 pts/0    S+   23:40   0:00 grep --color=auto apache

 ls -la / | grep home
drwxr-xr-x   3 kleber www-data  4096 Mar 13 16:10 home
ls -la | grep kleber
drwxr-xr-x  3 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 13 16:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 kleber www-data 4096 Mar 16 23:40 kleber
```

Comment: home is mostly a bad idea to use for. ehy not /var/www/domain and dont forget to chsnge the owner to www-admin

Comment: I made work before, but had to reinstall the server and can't remember what I did in the previous installation.

Comment: you have to fix the ownerships of the path. thats what it is telling, maybe even youve reinstalled it, ehy not thinking about to move the files to the best practices /var/www?

Comment: Apache is running with the same user that owns the folder inside the path, is this enough? or I have something else to look at?

Comment: tell us the chmod of direcotry for home, home/user and home/user/web

Comment: I just update the question with the related commands and their responses.

Comment: ps aux|grep apache still missing and ls / |grep home, cd /home, ls |grep kleber

Comment: update the question again to include that

Comment: just a question i see you deny (Require all denied) for / maybe that is yout issue?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
DocumentRoot /home/kleber/www/kleber
```

then perhaps you should add

```
<Directory /home/kleber/www/kleber>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to your configuration.